# Taking help from Jinn

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, jinn

Is it allowed in Islam to take help from good and Salih Jinn for good purpose??

Please describe your answer with the reference of Qur'aan and Ahhadiths.

Comment: Any authentic fatwa from Ulama about taking help from Jinn.
Please mention it with your answer.

Comment: Maybe, you should focus on checking if the answers have references before accepting as you would do normally. Peace!

Comment: how do you take "help from Jinn" ?

Comment: @amphibient I am not talking about myself.

Comment: i mean how does ONE physically take help from jinn ?  i am referring to the action you were questioning

Comment: I will tell you tomorrow with reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hazrat Suleman(A.S) used to take work from jins and were obviously for good purpose so it can be derived that a person can also take work from Jins for good purpose.

Similarly from another perspective Allah the almighty created man superior to Jins and superior always dominates the inferior so it can be deduced that as man is superior to Jins so it can control Jins too but obviously it should be for good purpose otherwise such acts cannot be justified.

This is my own opinion and my own interpretation. Many scholars also control Jins but I do not know what are their argument in this case.

Comment: You cannot mention your reference but I am satisfy with your answer.

Comment: well not everyone or anyone could take help from Jinn I guess need more elaboration.

Comment: **Oh! I see. So, as Hazrath Suleman (A.S) controlled/talked to each and every animal, can you do that too, apart from taking help from Jinn??**

Comment: As far as I know, the only intersection between the sets of humans and Jinn happens between the bad guys of both sects. Please think over. Peace!

Comment: @azam, From your philosophy I can conclude that as talking to animals can't be done then controlling Jins is also impossible. Do you really think that way? I am taking those things from the era of Hazrat Suleman(A.S) which we are capable of doing such as controlling Jins as people now a days control Jins. There is no doubt that people can't understand animals language but if I use your philosophy then if talking to animals is impossible then controlling Jins would be impossible too but people do control them now a days so you're point is invalid.

Comment: @azam, I know a scholar who is controlling a Jin and he is a scholar so he is not a bad person and use Jin for good purpose.

Comment: Dear, Hazrath Suleman talked to both Jinn and animals alike in their language. He was gifted something special. Today, even normal people can control both Jinn and animals (both by training), but, the probability of Jinn being controlled by humans for a **good cause** is believed to be **very very low**. And, as far as I know, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) has not been reported to have controlled Jinn.

Comment: See also: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83g9A_hrT8g) or if time permits other videos like those.

Comment: @azam, and I am only allowing those people who use them for good purpose. I haven't heard of prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) to have controlled Jin but can you tell me some references which prohibits the controlling of Jins? If not then it is not prohibited and some scholars have also controlled Jins so they must have thought about it before controlling them. But you are entitled to have an opinion and I respect that. Please note that the above answer is just an opinion and I request people to search about it before controlling a Jin. I am not a scholar and people are free to make their own choice.

Comment: One day at the night prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) was returning back from some where at the night time he was performing namaz on the way, on that time one jamat of jin passed from that area, jamat of jin heard tilavat of quran and they accepted islam http://www.islamcan.com/jinn-stories/a-group-of-jinns-meet-prophet-muhammad.shtml#.VdSEVZf8Ok0

Comment: Ridiculous. Using the Jinn's power is Sihr and shirk. And Allah specifically gave the power to control Jinn to Sulaiman (AS), and until Allah gives you prophetic permission it is not possible to control Jinn without doing Shirk

Answer (score -2):

assalam alaikum 
seeking help from jinn is entirely shirk
Suleiman as didn't get help from jinn but he commanded it to work for him by Allah's will 
there are groups who argue that seeking help from jinn is waseelathushirk are in complete deviation 
quran in soorah aaraf ayah 27 says human cannot see Jinn
we cant find anywhere in the time of prophet sws or sahabi or tabeen seeking help from the jinn

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Comment: Excuse me, I am a westerner and only slowly, very slowly learning about Islam. Why is seeking help from a jinn shirk? Because it is not asking help from Allah? So what exactly is the difference form asking help from someone up in the bureaucracy? Or from a doctor?